# issues installing from private repo r package

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I'm a bit confused on what I am missing here.

I have a private R package.  I am trying to install with `devtools::install_git('myaccount/myprivate_package')`

I get the following error:

```
Installation failed: Error in 'git2r_clone': unsupported URL protocol
```

I did some searching and it seems to talk about this git2r package being missing(its not), but when I try and re-install it, nothing changes.

I then use `devtools::install_github('myaccount/myprivate_package')` and I get this message:

```
Skipping install of 'myprivate_package' from a github remote, the SHA1 (3055a72e) has not changed since last install.
  Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
```

Can someone help me understand what is going on here so I don't run into this issue again?

Comment: I'm assuming that you meant to write (using BNF notation): `devtools::install_git('<myaccount_string>/myprivate_package')`. Did you try adding the force parameter?

Comment: The second message is saying that the code in the repo is that same as what you currently have installed so there is no need to install